# Fluent NHibernate "Could not resolve property"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have read a lot of the questions about that same error but none since to match my exact problem. I'm trying to access the property of an object, itself part of a root object, using Fluent NHibernate. Some answers say I need to use projections, others that I need to use join, and I think it should work through lazy loading.

Here are my two classes along with the Fluent mappings:

**Artist class**

```
public class Artist
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public virtual string MusicBrainzId { get; set; }
    public virtual string TheAudioDbId { get; set; }

    public Artist() { }
}

public class ArtistMap : ClassMap<Artist>
{
    public ArtistMap()
    {
        LazyLoad();
        Id(a => a.Id);
        Map(a => a.Name).Index("Name");
        HasMany(a => a.Albums)
            .Cascade.All();
        Map(a => a.MusicBrainzId);
        Map(a => a.TheAudioDbId);
    }
}
```

**Album class**

```
public class Album
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string TheAudioDbId { get; set; }
    public virtual string MusicBrainzId { get; set; }

    public Album() { }
}

public class AlbumMap : ClassMap<Album>
{
    public AlbumMap()
    {
        LazyLoad();
        Id(a => a.Id);
        References(a => a.Artist)
            .Cascade.All();
        Map(a => a.Name).Index("Name");
        HasMany(a => a.Tracks)
            .Cascade.All();
        Map(a => a.ReleaseDate);
        Map(a => a.TheAudioDbId);
        Map(a => a.MusicBrainzId);
    }
}
```

And the error happens when this code is interpreted:

```
var riAlbum = session.QueryOver<Album>()
                .Where(x => x.Name == albumName && x.Artist.Name == artist)
                .List().FirstOrDefault();
```

The error happens when Fluent NHibernate tries to resolve the x.Artist.Name value:

> {"could not resolve property: Artist.Name of: Album"}

What would be the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to think of your QueryOver query as (nearly) directly translating into SQL. With this in mind, imagine this SQL query:

```sql
select
    Album.*
from
    Album
where
    Album.Name = 'SomeAlbumName' and
    Album.Artist.Name = 'SomeArtistName'
```

This won't work because you can't access a related table's properties like that in a SQL statement. You need to create a join from `Album` to `Artist` and *then* use a `Where` clause:

```
var riAlbum = 
    session.QueryOver<Album>()
               .Where(al => al.Name == albumName)
           .JoinQueryOver(al => al.Artist)
               .Where(ar => ar.Name == artistName)
           .List()
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, since you're using `FirstOrDefault`, you may want to consider moving that logic to the database end. Currently, you're pulling back every record matching your criteria and then taking the first one. You could use `.Take` to limit the query to 1 result:

```
var riAlbum = 
    session.QueryOver<Album>()
               .Where(al => al.Name == albumName)
           .JoinQueryOver(al => al.Artist)
               .Where(ar => ar.Name == artistName)
           .Take(1)
           .SingleOrDefault<Album>();
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for explaining the reason behind too!

Comment: awesome explenation!

Answer (score 4):

Another explanation is that you are missing your mapping of this property or field in a NHibernateClassMapping definition.  I came here about why I was getting this error based on the following scenario.

```
 var query = scheduleRepository.CurrentSession().Query<Schedule>()
                .Where(x => x.ScheduleInfo.StartDate.Date < dateOfRun.Date);
```

This was giving me a Could Not Resolve Property error for StartDate.  This was a head scratcher, since I use this syntax all the time.

My mapping file was the following:

```
public class ScheduleInfoMapping : NHibernateClassMapping<ScheduleInfo>
    {
        public ScheduleInfoMapping()
        {
            DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type");
            Map(x => x.Detail).MapAsLongText();
        }
    }
```

which was missing the StartDate.  Changed to:

```
public class ScheduleInfoMapping : NHibernateClassMapping<ScheduleInfo>
    {
        public ScheduleInfoMapping()
        {
            DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type");
            Map(x => x.Detail).MapAsLongText();
            Map(x => x.StartDate);
        }
    }
```

Which resolved the error.

Comment: You saved my life buddy i forgot to map the property.