# NHibernate Like restriction on nested string properties

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

For simplicity, let's guess there are two entities:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ChildEntity Child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildEntity
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I need to find all entities where either `Value` or `Child.Value` are insensitive like specified string `query`.

That's what I have by now:

```
Entity entity = null;
ChildEntity child = null;

var nhibernateQuery = session
    .QueryOver(() => entity)
    .JoinAlias(() => entity.Child, () => child);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
{
    nhibernateQuery = nhibernateQuery
        .Where(
            Restrictions.Or(
                Restrictions.On(() => entity).IsInsensitiveLike(query),
                Restrictions.On(() => child).IsInsensitiveLike(query)
            )
        );
}

return nhibernateQuery.List().ToArray();
```

I get the `NullReferenceException` - it seems like `Restrictions.On` does not handle alias correctly.

Another approach that I have tried is `.JoinQueryOver()` which is suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527409/fluent-nhibernate-could-not-resolve-property):

```
return session
   .QueryOver<Entity>()
       .Where(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Value", query))
   .JoinQueryOver(e => e.Child)
       .Where(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Value", query));
```

This thing works except for one thing: it returns all items where both `Value` **and** `Child.Value` are like `query`. I need the same thing, but with `or` logic.

What should be done to make it work? I would like to use `.QueryOver()`, either with or without aliases, but without `.CreateCriteria()`, but will appreciate if you help me with any working solution.

Comment: Have you added MatchMode option?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr Could you please explain what do you mean? `MatchMode` just affects how is string compared, isn't it? There is no more related code than in this minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by using NHibernate LINQ `.Query<>()`.
It can resolve all joins and relations by itself.
At the same time, `.Contains()` method is translated into case-insensitive `LIKE` statement for MS SQL which suits me needs.

```
var nhibernateQuery = session
    .Query<Entity>();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
{
    nhibernateQuery = nhibernateQuery
        .Where(e => e.Value.Contains(query) || e.Child.Value.Contains(query));
}

return nhibernateQuery.ToArray();
```